# Conditional probability for mixed distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-probability, self-learning

I trying to solve a problem involving $Y = X_{1} + \cdots + X_{M}$ and $M$. We have that all $X_{i}$ are independent of $M$. The $X$ are i.i.d. For simplicity lets assume that all $X_{i} \sim \mathrm{Gamma}(k,\theta)$ and $M \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda)$. I want to calculate the following $P(Y > \gamma)$. How I was thinking about solving this problem is as follows:
$$P(Y > \gamma | M) = \frac{P(Y > \gamma, M)}{P(M)} = \frac{P(Y > \gamma)P(M)}{P(M)} = P(Y > \gamma) = 1 - F_{gamma}(\gamma),$$
where $F_{gamma}(\gamma)$ is the Gamma CDF. For some reason I don't feel like I'm doing it right. Any ideas on how I can calculate $P(Y > \gamma)$ or references texts (should not be too heavy as I'm still trying to grasp this).

Comment: If the $X_i$ are independent of $M$ then why do you need to condition on $M$ to begin with? Do you mean to write $Y = X_1+\dots + X_M$ ?

Comment: Yes, I ment to write $Y = X_{1}, \ldots, X_{M}$ (I have changed it). So, finding $P(Y > \gamma)$ is just $1 - F_{gamma}(\gamma)$? I guess that $Y$ is still dependent on $M$ since $M$ determines how many $X$ we need to sum to get $Y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Y|M=m$ is the sum of $m$ i.i.d. Gammas with parameters $(k,\theta)$, so
$$
Y|M=m \sim \text{Gamma}(mk, \theta).
$$
From here, we use the law of total probability to write:
\begin{align*}
P(Y>y) 
&= \sum_{m=0}^\infty P(Y > y|M=m) P(M=m)\\
&= \sum_{m=0}^\infty P(\text{Gamma}(mk, \theta) > y) \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^m}{m!}\\
&= \sum_{m=0}^\infty \int_y^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma(mk)} \theta^{mk} x^{mk-1} e^{-x/\theta}dx  \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^m}{m!}\\
\end{align*}

I'm not really sure that this can be simplified further. Note that you can compute other properties in closed form, for example

$$
\mathbb{E} Y = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}[Y|M]) = \mathbb{E}[km\theta]=k\theta \mathbb{E}[m] = k\theta \lambda.
$$
See also this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/367158/sum-of-n-gamma-distributions-with-n-being-a-poisson-distribution) which derives the MGF.

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot. I'll also take a look at the post you have linked to.